# How to store user data locally in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, observableobject

I try to accomplish having an observable object with a published value `training`. On every change it should save the custom struct to the user defaults. On every load (AppState init) it should load the data:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    var trainings: [Training] {
        willSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(trainings) {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                 defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "trainings")
            }
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.trainings = []
        if let savedTrainings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "trainings") as? Data {
            if let loadedTraining = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Training].self, from: savedTrainings) {
                self.trainings = loadedTraining
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I know if this is best practice, but I want to save the data locally.
The code I wrote is not working and I can't figure out why.

I'm a beginner and I never stored data to a device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call the `init` method the first line resets the value stored in `UserDefaults` and in-turn returns the empty array instead of the value that was previously stored. Try this modification to your `init` method to fix it:

```
init() {
    if let savedTrainings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "trainings") as? Data,
        let loadedTraining = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Training].self, from: savedTrainings) {
        self.trainings = loadedTraining
    } else {
        self.trainings = []
    }
}
```

Better Approach: A much better approach would to modify your `trainings` property to have a `get` and `set` instead of the current setup. Here is an example:

```swift
var trainings: [Training] {
    set {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
             defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "trainings")
        }
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
    get {
        if let savedTrainings = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "trainings") as? Data,
            let loadedTraining = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Training].self, from: savedTrainings) {
            return loadedTraining
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Note: This can again be improved using Swift 5.1's `@PropertyWrapper`. Let me know in the comments if anyone wants me to include that as well in the answer.

Update: Here's the solution that makes it simpler to use `UserDefaults` using Swift's `@PropertyWrapper` as you have requested for:-

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct UserDefault<T: Codable> {
    var key: String
    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get {
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
                return try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @UserDefault(key: "trainings") var trainings: [Training]?
    @UserDefault(key: "anotherProperty") var anotherPropertyInUserDefault: AnotherType?
}
```

Comment: This ends in `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`. How do I need to modify the init() with the better approach?

Comment: Give the default `[]` when it's unsuccessful to set all the properties. I've updated check now.

Comment: Would be great of you could include the `@PropertryWrapper` solution as I am trying to use the latest state of coding.n Thank you!

Comment: just want to bring you question back in mind - a PropertyWrapper solution would be very helpful

Comment: Was busy due to work, I'll be updated the PropertyWrapper solution soon.

Comment: this is a very interesting solution with the @PropertyWraper. I am not 100% sure how to implement this.
Lets say, I have the following:
**class AppState: ObservableObject {
  @UserDefault(key: "achievements")           var achievements:           [String : Bool]?
}**
How can I read and write to it? In my test examples the value is always empty: e.g. **AppState().achievements?["Easy"] = true** ...
is this because you cannot combine this type of dictionary?